# Databricks, How to enforce delta table column to have unique values?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, unique, primary-key

I have defined a delta table in Databricks with a primary key:

```
%sql
 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table_pk (
  table_name STRING NOT NULL,
  label STRING NOT NULL,
  table_location STRING NOT NULL,
 
  CONSTRAINT test_table_pk_col PRIMARY KEY(table_name)  
  
  ) USING DELTA
LOCATION "abfss://raw@Table_Path"
```

I want column "table_name" to be unique. However, I can insert rows with the same "table_name" as below:

```
%sql
 
INSERT INTO test_table_pk 
VALUES ('table_2', 'label_2', 'path_2'), 
       ('table_2', 'label_2', 'path_3');
```

In the table:

[image]

I tried to add a unique constraint for column "table_name":

```
CONSTRAINT test_table_unique_col UNIQUE(table_name)
```

but, I get the error:

```
Only PRIMARY KEY and FOREIGN KEY constraints are currently supported
```

How can I add a constraint to the column "table_name" to accept only unique values?

Comment: In short you cannot, even for PK and FK these are not enforced: https://docs.databricks.com/tables/constraints.html#declare-primary-key-and-foreign-key-relationships. You'll need to handle this in your data loading logic.

Answer (score 1):

Primary and foreign keys are informational only and are not enforced. Foreign keys must reference a primary key in another table. This primary key is the parent constraint of the foreign key and the table this primary key is on is the parent table of the foreign key. Similarly, the foreign key is the child constraint of its referenced primary key; the table of the foreign key is the child table of the primary key.

You can declare primary keys and foreign keys as part of the table specification during table creation. You can also add or drop constraints on existing tables.

SOURCE : https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/tableconstraints